# How many "universes" are there in Star Trek canon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, parallel-universe

I just finished watching Star Trek:TOS. There were at least two episodes dealing with other dimensions, the mirror universe and the anti-matter universe.

How many "universes" are there in Star Trek canon, and is any reason given that explains their existence or how they exist alongside each other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few answers come to mind:

- There's the Mirror Universe from TOS, which reappears in later series.  It seems to be connected to the primary universe in some way.
- There's the antimatter universe, from TOS.
- There's a near-unlimited number of quantum realities seen in TNG 7x11, "Parallels".
- Then there's the alternate timeline created for the 2009 movie.

As far as I know, it is unknown if there's any overlap from these.  The Mirror Universe, Antimatter Universe, and 2009 Movie may or may not be a quantum reality from Parallels.

And in addition to the above, which specifically fall under "parallel universe", there are other dimensions/universes that seem unlikely to fall under that umbrella term:  Fluidic Space, the Q Continuum, and the one Dax accidentally created, for example.

Comment: I would suppose there are even uncountably infinite many "quantum realities" in Parallels. But I have no transcript to back that up.

Comment: I think Parallels makes it clear that they believe an essentially infinite number of parallel universes exists.

Comment: there is also a "parralel universe" episode in star trek enterprise,but it may be the same as the mirror universe in TOS.the episode is in season 4 i think.

Comment: @BBlake: In popular science fiction the word *infinite* (like the word *exponential*) is more often misused than used correctly, so without context it doesn't say anything at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @sam Yep, ENT 4x18 "In a Mirror, Darkly" is a direct sequel to the TOS 3x09 "The Tholian Web".  It reveals what happened to the USS Defiant that the TOS Enterprise was looking for - it ended up in the Mirror Universe and a century or so back in time.  (As a side note, this is the episode that canonizes the TOS ship designs as an in-universe stylistic choice, not a limitation of reallife technology)

Comment: Also, I would include fluidic space as an "alternate dimension".

Comment: Actually, we only know there are at least "two hundred eighty five thousand" as that is the number of hails they receive when the Enterprises start leaking into the main universe.